# Alterar atributo "src" com efeito fadeIn

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando alterar o atributo src de uma imagem com jquery. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, preciso apenas aplicar um efeito que não estou conseguindo colocar. Não sei se do jeito que fiz é a forma exata de se obter o resultado que quero.

html

```
<img id="slide" src="img/img.png"/>
<a id="um">um</a>
<a id="dois">dois</a>
<a id="tres">três</a>
```

jquery

```
$("body").on("click","#um", function(){
    $("#slide").attr("src","img/1.png").fadeIn(2000);
})

$("body").on("click","#dois", function(){
    $("#slide").attr("src","img/2.png").fadeIn(2000);
})

$("body").on("click","#tres", function(){
    $("#slide").attr("src","img/3.png").fadeIn(2000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O fadeIn só funciona em elementos ocultos.

Se a imagem estiver visível e você apenas trocar o src e chamar o fadeIn, não ocorrerá efeito algum.

Para que funcione corretamente você precisa se certificar que a imagem esteja oculta, e você pode conseguir isso inserindo o hide() antes do fadeIn:

```
$("body").on("click","#um", function(){
    $("#slide").attr("src","img/1.png").hide().fadeIn(2000);
})
```

Comment: ótimo! Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

Diego, não acredito que seja possível fazer um efeito de transição para a propriedade 'src', o máximo que é possível é usando um background-image.

```js
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll("[data-img]");

[].forEach.call(imagens, function (imagem, indice) {
  var atual = 0;
  var lista = imagem.dataset.img.split(',').map(function (img) { return img.trim(); });
  imagem.classList.add(lista[atual]);
  imagem.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var proximo = atual + 1 < lista.length ? atual + 1 : 0;    
    imagem.classList.toggle(lista[atual]);
    imagem.classList.toggle(lista[proximo]);
    atual = proximo;
  });
})
```

```css
[data-img] {
  background-size:     cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  transition-property: 'background-image';
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

.img-verao {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/63341.png');
}

.img-primavera {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70696.png');
}

.img-inverno {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/63341.png');
}

.img-outono {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/2130.png');
}
```

```html
<div data-img="img-verao, img-primavera, img-inverno, img-outono"></div>
<div data-img="img-verao, img-primavera, img-inverno, img-outono"></div>
<div data-img="img-verao, img-primavera, img-inverno, img-outono"></div>
<div data-img="img-verao, img-primavera, img-inverno, img-outono"></div>
```